# Full name of Windows user name (in Domain) using Python

Tags: windows, python, windows-domain

I want to retrieve the full name of a Windows computer user in Python.

I have found the equivalent batch command:

```
net user "%USERNAME%" /domain | FIND /I "Full Name"
```

that returns the full name (e.g. `Full Name   John Doe`).

I have done the following way by using `subprocess` but I am wondering if there is a more native way to do it with some Python modules.

```
import getpass
import subprocess
import re

username = getpass.getuser()
p = subprocess.Popen(
    'net user %s /domain' % username,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE
)
info, err = p.stdout.read(), p.stderr.read()
full_name = re.findall(r'Full Name\s+(.*\S)', info)

print(full_name)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments from @Bob, the following is working on Windows and is pure Python but it requires to install `pywin32` (based on [this Recipe](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66314-get-user-info-on-windows-for-current-user/)):

```
import win32api
import win32net

user_info = win32net.NetUserGetInfo(win32net.NetGetAnyDCName(), win32api.GetUserName(), 2)
full_name = user_info["full_name"]
```

Another shorter version of the script in the question using only `subprocess` is:

```
import subprocess

name = subprocess.check_output(
   'net user "%USERNAME%" /domain | FIND /I "Full Name"', shell=True
)
full_name = name.replace(b"Full Name", b"").strip()
```

*NOTE: for Python 2.7, in the last example, you will need to change the last line to* `...replace("Full Name", "").strip()`

Answer (score 4):

The more direct way to do this is to query Active Directory. You'd perform a lookup on the user, followed by getting the `displayName` attribute. (This maps to the `Full Name` displayed in Windows.)

---

You have two options here:

### Using a Python AD library, e.g. [pyad](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyad)

This is very Windows-specific, and requires the `pywin32` library. It relies on ADSI APIs, so it will only works on Windows.

```
from pyad import aduser
user = aduser.ADUser.from_cn(username)
print(user.get_attribute("displayName"))
```

How you get the username is up to you. You can use `getpass.getuser()`, `os.environ["USERNAME"]` (Windows-only), etc.

### Using a Python LDAP library, e.g. [ldap3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ldap3)

This follows the standard LDAP protocol, with a pure Python implementation, so should work from any client OS.

Using raw LDAP queries is rather more involved than the ADSI abstractions. I suggest you read the documentation (which has decent tutorials) and search for more tutorials on interacting with Microsoft AD via `ldap3`.

---

Note that one possible issue is that searching by username (CN) alone might get you the wrong object. It's possible to have multiple objects with the same CN across multiple OUs. If you want to be more precise, you might want to use a unique identifier like the SID.

Comment: Is there a method using Windows' "Net*()" functions? (Or, well, similar.) It would then work for any kind of account – local, nt4, ad...

Comment: @grawity Hm, I'd not even thought of that. With `pywin32` you could use `import win32net` and use [`win32net.NetUserGetInfo()`](http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32net__NetUserGetInfo_meth.html), which calls [`NetUserGetInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370654(v=vs.85).aspx). A level of 2 or higher includes a `full_name`. However, with a bit of testing, it appears that you have to specify the server to get a domain response anyway - querying a domain user (even the currently logged in one) against `None`/`localhost` fails.

Comment: Interesting answer, although I have an error while trying with pyad when doing `aduser.ADUser.from_cn`: `The specified query resturned 0 results. getSingleResults only functions with a single result.`. I believe I will stick to my ugly solution :)

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisT. Hm, that's interesting - it worked when I tested. I assume the machine you're running it on is joined to the domain, and that you are using a correct `username`? It *should* work with the same thing you pass into `net user /domain`. Failing that, you could try the `NetUserGetInfo` method. Or your subprocess method if you can accept the ugliness ;)